# Unable to create an object of type 'RemoteContext'

Tags: c#, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I have two DbContext files that are practically identical, the only difference being the connection string. In the first one it is generated within the constructor, whereas in the second on it is passed through the constructor.

the first file looks like this:

```cs
public class ApplicationContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Password> Passwords { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Group> Groups { get; set; }

    public string DbPath { get; }

    public ApplicationContext()
    {
        var path = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
        DbPath = Path.Join(path, "pwmanager.db");
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
        => options.UseSqlite($"Data Source={DbPath}");

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        _ = modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new PasswordConfig());
        _ = modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new GroupConfig());
    }
}
```

it works perfectly.

This one on the other hand:

```cs
public class RemoteContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Password> Passwords { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Group> Groups { get; set; }

    private string _ConnectionString { get; }

    public RemoteContext(string connectionString)
    {
        _ConnectionString = connectionString;
    }

    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
        => options.UseSqlServer(_ConnectionString);

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        _ = modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new PasswordConfig());
        _ = modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new GroupConfig());
    }
}
```

does not work at all, because when I try to create an initial migration I get

> Unable to create an object of type 'RemoteContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728

This makes no sense to me, as both files are practically identical to one another and within the EFCore documentation it says you can pass data through the constructor just like that (which is the only difference besides the name).

In the end the reason I am doing all of this is to have all the data from a local server be copied/read from a remote server whenever you start the application for data parity.

If anyone has any better suggestions for how to accomplish this please feel free to let me know.

Comment: SQL Server is not the same thing as SQLite - please correct your tags.

Comment: @DaleK I am aware that they are different, but my project is referencing both. Would it be more appropriate the have neither?

Comment: You tag the RDBMS you want a solution in, if its relevant to the solution. If its not relevant, don't tag either.